# Connect directly to the "local" database of primary MongoDB node in replica set

Tags: mongodb, etl

I need access to the OpLog of the primary of my replica set in MongoDB. I am developing an OpLog driven ETL job as it is far more efficient than simply querying and transferring data from the entire table.

I can access the OpLog easily with the following steps in the terminal:

```
mongo mymongoserver.com:10733/my-db -u oplogUser -pxxxxxxxx
```

Then I run:

```
use local
```

and then I can query the OpLog using:

```
db.oplog.rs.find()
```

My question is: Are there any settings I can pass to the mongo connect command to get me straight into the `local` database for the primary node?

I am using Talend Open Studio for my ETL needs. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

I have come across this from the guys at Stripe, which means that this is definitely possible! https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/building-real-time-systems-mongodb-using-oplog-stripe

Comment: Let me put it that way: If you have to ask this question, you surely should not fiddle with the oplog. Make sure you understand the replication mechanics *properly* before proceeding. Hint: the `local` database is both in no way and in some way different from other databases.

Comment: All I need to do is query it to extract the _id values of documents being created, updated, inserted and deleted - I could implement my own thing but this way seems far cleaner. I'm clear on the mechanics, and if Mongo can use this method to replicate internally, then surely it's the right way to go externally. Is there any other clean path to go down?

Comment: I have my doubts, but ervybody his: Simply connect to the replica set as usual and set the [read preference to "primary "](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#read-preference-reference). [Use a tailable cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/#create-tailable-cursor). Never, ever try to write or modify the oplog.